# How to make the jar file to been a service with install4j?

Tags: install4j

I already have the jar file of my application. I've created the installer with install4j and chosen the service executable type. However, after the installation none service is added to windows. Can anybody help me?

Comment: The "Service Option" option does not appear for me, the location would be between the Windows version information and the Windows manifest option, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add an "Install a service" action on the Installer->Screen & Actions step.

Comment: Thank you so much, i got it.